# Mysql regex find both words in text

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * `library` WHERE 
    ( 
    UCASE(  `text` ) REGEXP  '((^KEYWORD|[[.space.]]KEYWORD)([[.space.]]|[[.comma.]]|[[.period.]]|[[.colon.]]|[[.semicolon.]]|[[.apostrophe.]]|[[.quotation-mark.]]|[[.exclamation-mark.]]|[[.question-mark.]]))((^KEYWORD2|[[.space.]]KEYWORD2)([[.space.]]|[[.comma.]]|[[.period.]]|[[.colon.]]|[[.semicolon.]]|[[.apostrophe.]]|[[.quotation-mark.]]|[[.exclamation-mark.]]|[[.question-mark.]]))'
    )
```

** EDIT **

added an sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f822/2/0

In readable format this is:

```
SELECT * FROM `library` WHERE 
    ( 
    UCASE(  `text` ) REGEXP  '
            (
                (
                ^KEYWORD | [[.space.]]KEYWORD
                )
                (
                [[.space.]] |
                [[.comma.]] | 
                [[.period.]] | 
                [[.colon.]] |
                [[.semicolon.]] |
                [[.apostrophe.]] | 
                [[.quotation-mark.]] | 
                [[.exclamation-mark.]] | 
                [[.question-mark.]]
                )
            ) 

            (
                (
                ^KEYWORD2 | [[.space.]]KEYWORD2
                )
                (
                [[.space.]] |
                [[.comma.]] | 
                [[.period.]] | 
                [[.colon.]] |
                [[.semicolon.]] |
                [[.apostrophe.]] | 
                [[.quotation-mark.]] | 
                [[.exclamation-mark.]] | 
                [[.question-mark.]]
                )
            ) 
        )'
```

Now I need the query to do the following thing, and I'm hitting a brick wall here.

If keyword appears in text, starting the text or preceded by a space, followed by one of the special chars, then show the result.

This doesn't really work like I need it to, but I can't find in the documentation how to make a match if both appear. e.g. trying to match the string `"keyword,"`,`"keyword "` or `"keyword;"`

Then I need to match a same type of query for keyword 2.

Then both expressions for keyword and keyword2 need to be true and I only need those results.

For example the texts

```
A lazy brown fox jumped over the fence. 
Then he found a chicken. 
Then he ate the chicken and ran from the farmer.
```

and

```
A fox found a chicken. 
Then he ate the chicken and ran from the farmer.
Then fox jumped over the fence.
```

Should come op with he following keywords `fence` `chicken`

but this shouldn't match the following text

```
A lazy brown fox jumped over the fences. 
Then he found a chicken. 
Then he ate the chicken and ran from the farmer.
```

**ANSWER**

The final query has become

```
SELECT *
FROM`library`
WHERE
UCASE(`text` ) REGEXP '(^| )FENCE[[.space.][.comma.][.period.][.colon.][.semicolon.][.apostrophe.][.quotation-mark.][.exclamation-mark.][.question-mark.]]'
AND
UCASE(`text` ) REGEXP '(^| )CHICKEN[[.space.][.comma.][.period.][.colon.][.semicolon.][.apostrophe.][.quotation-mark.][.exclamation-mark.][.question-mark.]]'
```

because regex doesn't support random order searches, and since I don't wish to do *n* to the power of number of keywords search strings this is the best possible solution.

Thanks all for watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex `(^| )KEYWORD[- ,.:;'"!?]` and put two REGEXP tests in your WHERE clause ANDed together. The first part `(^| )` is a regex which allows us to match the start of the text or a space. Next comes the keyword which has to be matched as is and then a character class between `[]` for which a single character from the class has to match. It is like an OR for single characters instead of `|` for complete regexes.

```
SELECT *
FROM`library`
WHERE
UCASE(`text` ) REGEXP '(^| )KEYWORD[- ,.:;''"!?]'
AND
UCASE(`text` ) REGEXP '(^| )KEYWORD2[- ,.:;''"!?]'
```

Disclaimer : I have not tested the SQL statement and I can't remember if the apostrophe has to be doubled inside the string.

Comment: Could you explain please what does what in your regex? Regex isn't my forte anymore since I gave up perl 12 years ago...

Comment: Your query works wonderfully http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f822/6/0 but now I'm wondering if it's possible to do it all in one regex?

Comment: It is possible to make a single regex but it will be an ugly one, less readable than this one. You will have to consider the different cases: first keyword1 then keyword2 or first keyword2 then keyword1. I think this solution is better. And indeed as you wrote, when you get more than two keywords, it gets unmanageable quickly.